# Bash script and string compares

Tags: bash

All,

I have 2 version strings, e.g. "2.0.13" and "2.0.2". I need to compare the 2 versions and determine which is the higher version.

How does one do that using bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sort -V` (version sort):

```
echo -e "2.0.13\n2.0.2" | sort -V
```

results in:

```
2.0.2
2.0.13
```

Comment: +1: I was going to write an inline Perl script but that is really neat! I didn't know the `-V` option.

Answer (score 1):

From [bmk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651031/bmk)

> You can use sort -V (version sort)

That's the best answer if it works, but unfortunately not all `sort` commands have the `-V` option.

If yours doesn't, you'll have to switch to Perl. Newer versions of Perl allow for certain variables to be declared as versions by prefixing them with a lowercase "v". You can then compare them with the `gt` operator.

See [Perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have `-V`, I'm sure there should be a way to do this by combining:

- `-t .` to make sort split fields on full stops
- `-n` to make sort sort numerically
- `-k` to define the fields to sort on

But i can't make it work!

Comment: Yes, I also tried to get it to work this way. But without success :(